# Use jsp:forward to forward to another page

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I am learning about jsp and servlet. In an online tutorial, he used `<jsp: forward>` to move to another jsp page.

`<jsp:forward page="home"></jsp:forward>`

The directory tree: (eclipse)
[The directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RKL5.png)

I don't understand why when I run the program, the index.jsp file in the home directory is run. Why is he using `<jsp: forward page = "home"> </ jsp: forward>` instead of  `<jsp: forward page = "/ WEB-INF / views / home / index.jsp "> </ jsp: forward>`

Can someone please explain me the using the relative url in web project.
Thank you so much !

Comment: Is there a servlet mapping for "home" in the web.xml?

Comment: There is no a servlet mapping for "home" in the web.xml. May I ask if there is a connection between jsp: forward and webservlet annotation?.I  have a servlet with ```@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/home"})``` in the project.

Comment: Yes, the `page` attribute is not limited to another JSP file, any valid URI in the application will work as long as the client can reach that URI. And usually the contents of WEB-INF are not directly serveable to the client.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much. In this tutorial he used filter for the request from the user. But it doesn't seem to work for ```<jsp: forward>```.right?